# Displaying a PDF on a mobile device in SAPUI5

Tags: pdf, sapui5

Does anyone know if this can be done? as far as I know there is a PDFViewer which works fine for desktop but doesn't display the PDF if you run the application on a mobile device. Have any of you found any workarounds for this?

I've tried using PDFviewer but unfortunately it doesn't have support for mobile devices.

Comment: The PDFViewer should automatically display a download button since mobile browsers afaik cannot render PDF files.